# Windows 8, Windows Phone 8 Application size limits

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone, marketplace, xap, windows-phone-8

Is there any information available regarding application (xap) size limits for

1. Windows Phone 7 = 225MB
2. Windows Phone 7.8 = 225MB?
3. Windows 8 (Metro)
4. Windows Phone 8

Comment: To be clear the first requirements allow 400MB apps  http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/10/29/updated-version-of-windows-phone-7-application-certification-requirements.aspx

Comment: BTW. Do you have a scenario when your app will be bigger than 255MB?

Comment: Well, yes. That's why i'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size limit for a Windows 8 Metro style app package is 2GB.  See [Package Format Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694075.aspx).  I do not believe there are any details out there yet about Phone 7.8 or Phone 8 in terms of XAP size.

Answer (score 6):

The size limit for a Windows Phone 8 is 1GB according to 4.1.1 of the app submission requirements, found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184844%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).  This was last updated a week ago (Dec 12, 2012).  Nothing was specifically mentioned for WP7.8, so I assume it's still 225MB.